# How to delete millions of records from a mysql table without slowdown

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, miva

Is there a good way to delete lots of records without slowing down a website?

I need to delete millions of records from a MySQL table that has no indexes and no primary key. I read on SO and various tutorials on the web that the basic strategy is to limit the delete query, sleep for a second or two between deletes, and repeat the process until finished. I also (using PDO) am running a commit after all loops complete.

That worked fine last week, but every time I ran the script, the database slowed down and we received many complaints about the site being slow etc. This is on a Miva Merchant baskets table, not that it really matters.

I'm almost done trimming the table so I could just suffer through it and finish. But there must be a better way...?

Here is the relevant code:

```
$database->beginTransaction();
$selectLimit = 4900; // mysql will lock the entire table at 5000+.....
$loopLimit = 10;
$date = "1456272001"; // 2016-02-24

for( $i = 0; $i < $loopLimit; $i++ ) {
    $startTime = time();
    $oldBaskets = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM s01_Baskets WHERE CAST(lastupdate AS UNSIGNED) < '" . $date . "' LIMIT " . $selectLimit . "");
    if ( $oldBaskets->execute() ) {
        $deletes = $oldBaskets->rowCount();
        $totalDeletes += $deletes;
        $duration = time() - $startTime;
        echo "\ndeleted '" . $deletes . "' entries";
        echo "\n-- took '" . $duration . "' seconds";
    }
    sleep(2);
}
$database->commit();
```

Comment: How about adding an index to the lastUpdate column?

Comment: @Borjante, I don't know much about how MySQL indexes work but my concerns about your suggestion were that A) building the index would also slow down the database, and I would have no control over how long it would last (right now the table is about 1.9m records), and B) lastUpdate is an epoch timestamp stored as a varchar and therefore is almost always unique for each row, so does an index help on such a column?

Comment: B) It will help, for sure, at a little cost of INSERT times but I would for sure use it anyways.

Regarding A), yes it's probable that it will slow down the DB but, you don't have to index everyday, and I understand that you are going to have to delete rows more than once, so I would go this way.

Maybe another stackOverflowGeniues has a better idea

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on `lastupdate` and modify your query a little:

```
DELETE
FROM    s01_Baskets
WHERE   lastupdate < :date
ORDER BY
        lastupdate
LIMIT   :limit
```

Having an index on `lastupdate` will allow MySQL to use it both for ordering and filtering, so only the records which have to be deleted will be visited by the engine.

Without an index, `MySQL` has to examine all the records in your database as it reads them, before it reaches the limit.

Using `CAST` on an indexed field in MySQL makes the expression unsargable (unable to use the index for filtering), that's why you should convert the expression you are comparing against (`$date`), not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out I was unable to create an index on the `lastupdate` field because it wasn't unique. I did remove the `CAST` and the query seemed to work the same, which I was surprised about since `lastupdate` is a varchar.

Comment: @MikeWillis: you can create an index on non-unique fields too. `CREATE INDEX ix_s01_baskets ON s01_Baskets (lastupdate)`

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you have no indexes and no auto-incremented IDs I would personally go for direct SQL like this:

*Note: You should probably do this when there is minimal activity on the system*

```sql
RENAME TABLE s01_Baskets TO s01_Baskets_to_be_deleted;

CREATE TABLE s01_Baskets LIKE s01_Baskets_to_be_deleted;

INSERT INTO s01_Baskets (col1, col2, ..., coln)
SELECT *
FROM s01_Baskets_to_be_deleted
WHERE lastupdate >= '2016-02-24 00:00:00';

DROP TABLE s01_Baskets_to_be_deleted;
```

The first two should execute relatively quickly and your users will not notice a slowdown. All of their interaction will simply be routed to your new empty table.

The third command will re-insert the records your wish to keep.

As for the `DROP` command, it might slow down the DB a little in terms of disk I/O but since none of the records are being interacted with then your users should experience almost no slowdown.

---

Also, another reason that deletion is so slow and intense is because MySQL will log each row and if you have any active triggers then those must be executed before the delete can be performed.